# Multi-colored triangle strip with JOGL

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I need to draw red and yellow triangles in a strip, and each triangle should have different color. This is my code so far:

```
Position drawPos = begPos.copy().offsetX(A);

gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // red
gl.glVertex3f(drawPos.getX(), drawPos.getY(), 0f);
drawPos.offsetX(-A);
gl.glVertex3f(drawPos.getX(), drawPos.getY(), 0f);
drawPos.offset2DAngle(-60f, A);
gl.glVertex3f(drawPos.getX(), drawPos.getY(), 0f);
gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // yellow
drawPos.offsetX(-A);
gl.glVertex3f(drawPos.getX(), drawPos.getY(), 0f);
gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // red
drawPos.offset2DAngle(-60f, A);
gl.glVertex3f(drawPos.getX(), drawPos.getY(), 0f);
gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // yellow
drawPos.offsetX(-A);
gl.glVertex3f(drawPos.getX(), drawPos.getY(), 0f);
gl.glEnd();
```

Im expecting to see two yellow and two red triangles with sharp edges and no gradients, but im getting this

[image: triangle strip, but with gradient]

I tried `gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);`, and `gl.glPolygonMode(GL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL2.GL_FILL);`, and even

```
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

But it all doesnt work for me

Edit: Position class i just my little thing to reduce and simplify code in drawing methods

Comment: @Rabbid76 oh, its actually gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_FLAT);, thats why it didnt work when i first tried, thanks. Post that as an answer, please

Comment: By the way, using the immediate mode (i.e glBegin/glEnd/etc) instead of the retained mode is highly discouraged even for developers who go on using the fixed pipeline. I advise you to use at least vertex arrays and preferably VBOs and VAOs. The immediate mode is often more error prone, less supported in modern drivers and has many performance pitfalls.

Comment: nah im only starting to learn OpenGL, maybe will consider doing the thing later on

Comment: I personally discourage the use of the immediate mode even for pedagogical purposes. Rather use com.jogamp.opengl.util.ImmModeSink in a phase of transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a triangle strip always 2 vertices of 2 triangles are shared (see [Triangle primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives)). Thus, the color assigned to these vertices is also shared. A vertex cannot have 2 different color attributes. Either draw 2 `GL_TRIANGLES` instead of one `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` or change the shading model to flat shading:

```java
gl.glShadeModel(GL.GL_FLAT);
```

Comment: Yes, and for some versions this constant is in GL2 interface, not GL

Comment: @StreakerOne Actually, GL_FLAT is in com.jogamp.opengl.fixedfunc.GLLightingFunc and GL2 inherits of this interface in JOGL 2. The source code above has a chance to work with JOGL 1 which is obsolete.